# Default connection for timeout value in Android DefaultHttpClient

Tags: android, http

What is the default connection timeout value for `DefaultHttpClient` in Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connection timeout default value is zero, which means timeout is not used.

Comment: Is it wait for upto for server response..There is no chance of Timed out exception if we not set the value?

Comment: there's a socket timeout, which says how long we are going to wait until data comes. not sure, what's default value for that one.